# Python открытие файла в своей директории

Tags: python

Как открыть файл Python в свой директории? Когда я использую

```
os.openfile("Additional.exe")
```

или

```
subprocess.Popen("Additional.exe")
```

файл запускается, и при попытке открыть файл из директории где находится Additional.exe, Возникает ошибка `FileNotExists`, т.к. оно ищет в директории где находится main.exe

Если вы не поняли текст, можете попробовать посмотреть на картинке, там я вроде проще описал
[image: Описание проблемы]

P.S. Исполозовался PyInstaller

Comment: может быть прописать полный путь?

Comment: У конечного пользователя программа может лежать где угодно, не совсем хороший вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не уверен, но если ты хочешь вызвать эксешник из другой директории, то, предположительно, ты знаешь где она находится относительно того места, откуда ты вызываешь файл.
В таком случае вместо того чтобы задавать абсолютный путь ты можешь попробовать задать относительный какими-то манипуляциями типа этих:

```py
your_dir = 'dir2'
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.path.split(os.getcwd())[0], your_dir))
```

Выполнив код выше ты сможешь перейти из текущей директории в соседнюю с названием dir2, откуда уже сможешь достать нужный тебе файл.

Comment: Для формирования путей есть os.path.join() и не придётся исхитряться со всякими split

Comment: До этого ошибся с абсолютными путями из-за чего не показал вариант с `os.path.join()`. Исправил ответ.